# Extracting a part of a row into a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a file with contents as:

```
1 a 9 11 22 33 44 55
2 b 4 99 88 77 66 44
3 c 8 88 33 22 55 22
```

I want to parse the file and extract them into 2 `numpy` arrays as

```
letters = [a b c]
values  = [[11 22 33 44 55], [99 88 77 66 44], [88 33 22 55 22]]
```

How can I do this in the most efficient way. Currently I am using a for loop and if i do the same with `numpy.loadtxt()`. I need to read the file twice due to difference in data types.

My code is:

```
letters = np.loadtxt( train_file, usecols=[1], dtype=str)
values  = np.loadtxt( train_file, usecols=range(3,7))
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: What makes you think that is inefficient?

Comment: `pandas` does OK with reading mixed-data CSVs.  Except this isn't a CSV. Still, you might try importing pandas and running, `DF = pandas.read_csv("/path/to/file",sep=" ",header=None)` and examining `DF`.

Comment: Also, if it only takes 2 lines in numpy and you are happy with it, it might be best to stick with what you have. Pandas won't be substantially faster and will also need adaptation.

Comment: I feel it might be inefficient as I am reading the file twice. The file is really huge with around 30,000 lines and each row has 150 elements.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to read the desired columns and then separate them as shown below:

```
data  = np.loadtxt( train_file, usecols=[1]+range(3,7))
letters=data[:,0]
values=np.delete(data,0,axis=1)
```